# how to add a row to a Datetime Multiindex Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, multi-index

> How would I go about adding a row to the top of this dataframe. This
>   is downloaded data. I cannot use a specific row index in the formula
>   because the first Datetime indice changes all the time. I cannot also use a 
>   specific label for the inner index as it could be Datetime. Is there a
>   way to generalize this?
>
> I tried this

```
df[df.index.min()[0])) - dt.timedelta(minutes=5), :] = [list to add]
```

> however it only add a row at the end of the Dataframe. Sorting,

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

> did not help because I guess I am dealing with 2 levels of index here;
>   which would explain why the row sticks to the bottom of the frame.

```
                        A      B      C        D     E

2006-04-28 00:00:00                                    
             A        69.62  69.62  6.518   65.09  69.62
             B
             C
2006-05-01 00:00:00  
            A         71.5   71.5  6.522   65.16   71.5
            B
            C
2006-05-02 00:00:00   
            A        72.34  72.34  6.669   66.55  72.34
            B
            C
```

The final result should look like this:
`X`'s being the elements in the list/array to be added.

```
                        A      B      C        D     E
        NEWROW          X1     X2    X3       X4    X5

2006-04-28 00:00:00                                    
             A        69.62  69.62  6.518   65.09  69.62
             B
             C
2006-05-01 00:00:00  
            A         71.5   71.5  6.522   65.16   71.5
            B
            C
2006-05-02 00:00:00   
            A        72.34  72.34  6.669   66.55  72.34
            B
            C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and [`sortlevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html) for me does **not** work with `Multiindex`:

So you can use little `hack` - first [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with second level `Stats`, then [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and last [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) back with parameter `append=True`:

```
df1 = df1.sort_index()

df1.loc[((df1.index.min()[0]) -  dt.timedelta(minutes=5), 'SUM'),:] = 
df1.loc[(slice(None), slice('price')),:].sum()

df1 = df1.reset_index('Stats')
df1 = df1.sort_index(axis=0).set_index('Stats', append=True)
print (df1)
                                 A       B       C       D       E
Date                Stats                                         
2006-04-27 23:55:00 SUM     213.46  213.46  19.709  196.80  213.46
2006-04-28 00:00:00 price    69.62   69.62   6.518   65.09   69.62
                    std        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
                    weight     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2006-05-01 00:00:00 price    71.50   71.50   6.522   65.16   71.50
                    std        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
                    weight     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2006-05-02 00:00:00 price    72.34   72.34   6.669   66.55   72.34
                    std        NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
                    weight     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: hey jezrael :), thanks! however, i get this: KeyError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (1)'

Comment: Try first `sort_index()`, I add it to solution.

Comment: you did it again!:))

Comment: hi jezrael i posted one last question..think you can get a crack at it? :) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39583914/reaching-prior-rows-within-a-multiindex-panda-dataframe)